# Mantaflow Several flow source, one domain

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, mantaflow

[image]I have several flow sources but one domain. I need liquid to flow out all 5 sources. I have set up the flow inflow settings on the flow sources. When I bake it, fluid only comes out of one source. What to do?

File on https://drive.google.com/file/d/17n3GbCdHc3o7waMRrIQ3y3PeACdCqWkS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Provide blend file. Without further info we can just guess …

Comment: To add to above comment. You can use https://pasteall.org/blend/ . Post link here in the comments.

Comment: @Sorry. already updated it